# How to stop loading a Page when navigating back?

Tags: windows-phone-7

in my project ! When backPage i use :

```
if (NavigationService.CanGoBack == true)
                NavigationService.GoBack();
```

In Project , i load data from web by using WebClient, when user go to Page 2 and back to page 1 ,users have to wait very long (when the load is complete, users can back)

How to stop Load and return to the previous page in the fastest time!

Please help me !

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution will be to cache the data that was downloaded when you first went to the page. (Writing this in a file in IsolatedStorage will probably be easiest.) Then when returning to the page, load the data from the file data rather than downloading it again.

Of course, dont' forget to manage the cache and clear/delete the file when you don't want to use it any more. ;)

Comment: Thank Matt Lacey !
But i want back Page fast !

Comment: @thongaduka if the delay in loading the page isn't the web request then you'll need to look into what is causing the page to take a long time to load. Without your code it's going to be hard for anyone to help.